# how to draw multiple polygons using mouse events

Tags: python, opencv, polygon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQTJF.png)[edited]
I'm trying to draw multiple and independent polygons through mouse events and the function cv2.polylines(), but I can't draw them in the same image and separated, there is allways a line connecting them. 
Can anyone help me please.
I am new to all this. 
Thank you in advanced.

```
class PolygonDrawer(object):
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        self.window_name = window_name  # Name for our window
        self.done = False  # Flag signalling we're done
        self.current = (0, 0)  # Current position, so we can draw the line-in-progress
        self.points = []  # List of points defining our polygon
        self.polygon = 1  # number of polygons

    def on_mouse(self, event, x, y, buttons, user_param):
        # Mouse callback that gets called for every mouse event (i.e. moving, clicking, etc.)
        if self.done:  # Nothing more to do
            return
        if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            # We want to be able to draw the line-in-progress, so update current mouse position
            self.current = (x, y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.current = (x, y)
            # Left click means adding a point at current position to the list of points
            print("Adding point #%d with position(%d,%d) to polygon number %d" % (len(self.points), x, y, self.polygon))
            self.points.append((x, y))
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
            # Right click means we're done
            print("Completing polygon with %d points." % len(self.polygons_points))
            self.polygon = 1
            self.done = True
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            self.points.clear()
            #  double click left button adds new polygon
            self.polygon = self.polygon + 1
            self.points.append((x, y))

    def run(self, path):
        # read the image
        img_run = cv2.imread(path, 0)
        new_img_run = img_run.copy()
        height = img_run.shape[0]
        width = img_run.shape[1]

        # Let's create our working window and set a mouse callback to handle events
        cv2.namedWindow(self.window_name, flags=cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow(self.window_name, img_run)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        cv2.setMouseCallback(self.window_name, self.on_mouse)

        while not self.done:
            # This is our drawing loop, we just continuously draw new images
            # and show them in the named window
            if len(self.points) > 0:
               # for i in range(len(self.polygons_points)):
                # Draw all the current polygon segments
                cv2.polylines(new_img_run, np.array([self.points]), False, FINAL_LINE_COLOR, 3)
                # And  also show what the current segment would look like
                # cv2.line(self.list_img[1], self.points[-1], self.current, WORKING_LINE_COLOR, 5)

            # Update the window
            cv2.imshow(self.window_name, new_img_run)
            # And wait 50ms before next iteration (this will pump window messages meanwhile)
            if cv2.waitKey(50) == 27:  # ESC hit
                self.done = True

        # User finished entering the polygon points, so let's make the final drawing
        if len(self.points) > 0:
            cv2.fillPoly(new_img_run, np.array([self.points]), FINAL_LINE_COLOR)

            # creates the an all black image with the size of the original image
            mask_poly = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
            # creates the polygon in the black image, creates the mask
            cv2.fillPoly(mask_poly, np.array([self.points]), FINAL_LINE_COLOR)
            # applies the original image over the mask, with the white polygon, making the image of the polygon
            # we want
            result_poly = np.bitwise_and(img_run, mask_poly)
```

I've inlcuded some of a code that I adapted to my needs, but it still doesn't draw independet polygons.

Comment: probably, currently you are creating a single list of points with you mouse events. You will need a signal to end creation of this list and to start a new list. Then you'll manage a list of polygons and you can draw each one individually with an individual call of cv2.polylines

Comment: Hi @Micka!
Thank you for your answer. I've edited my question, including some code that I'm currently working. I've tried to clean my list and then add the new points to a new polygon. But it still as lines connecting the polygons.

Comment: can you show an image? Might be possible that I dont understand the problem correctly.

Comment: can you debug whether cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE is called instead/before cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK? unfortunately I dont have much time atm

Comment: I've posted the image, can you see it? (I'm new here so I can't post it in the question, it had to be a link). There are lines connecting my three polygons, which I don't want, because that gives me problems when I've to draw several, and some lines cut the other polygons, and when I fill them, some of the get distorted.

Comment: I will try, thank you soo much for the help!